# How can we change the positions of the labels on a Tikz-cd commutative diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

With this code

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
            \begin{tikzcd}
                & B \arrow{dr}{g} \\
                A \arrow{ur}{f} \arrow{rr}{h} && C
            \end{tikzcd} &
            \begin{tikzcd}
                & \text{Hom}(B,G) \arrow{dl}{\widetilde f}\\
                \text{Hom}(A,G) && \text{Hom}(C,G) \arrow{ll}{\widetilde h} \arrow{ul}{\widetilde g} 
            \end{tikzcd}
        \end{tabular}
```

I obtain the following diagrams

[image]

As you can find, the labels of the second diagram have been "reflected" with respect to the given arrows. I would like to remedy this, however, I don't know how to do so.

Thanks in advance for your help.

PS: I would like to give a working sample of code, but I don't know which packages are required for this to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can swap labels. Here are three of them:

1. You can swap the labels with `every arrow/.append style={swap}`.
2. You can swap individual labels by adding `[swap]` to the arrows.
3. If you use the `quotes` syntax, swapping the labels is as simple as adding a prime.

Example codes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering\begin{tabular}{cc}
            \begin{tikzcd}
                & B \arrow{dr}{g} \\
                A \arrow{ur}{f} \arrow{rr}{h} && C
            \end{tikzcd} &
            \begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={swap}]
                & \text{Hom}(B,G) \arrow{dl}{\widetilde f}\\
                \text{Hom}(A,G) && \text{Hom}(C,G) \arrow{ll}{\widetilde h} \arrow{ul}{\widetilde g} 
            \end{tikzcd}
        \end{tabular}
\caption{All labels swapped at once with the key \texttt{every arrow/.append
style=\{swap\}}.}       
\end{figure}
%
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering\begin{tabular}{cc}
            \begin{tikzcd}
                & B \arrow{dr}{g} \\
                A \arrow{ur}{f} \arrow{rr}{h} && C
            \end{tikzcd} &
            \begin{tikzcd}
                & \text{Hom}(B,G) \arrow[swap]{dl}{\widetilde f}\\
                \text{Hom}(A,G) && \text{Hom}(C,G) \arrow[swap]{ll}{\widetilde h} \arrow[swap]{ul}{\widetilde g} 
            \end{tikzcd}
        \end{tabular}
\caption{Individual labels swapped by adding \texttt{[swap]} to the arrows.}       
\end{figure}
%
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering\begin{tabular}{cc}
            \begin{tikzcd}
                & B \arrow{dr}{g} \\
                A \arrow{ur}{f} \arrow{rr}{h} && C
            \end{tikzcd} &
            \begin{tikzcd}
                & \text{Hom}(B,G) \arrow[dl,"\widetilde f"']\\
                \text{Hom}(A,G) && \text{Hom}(C,G) 
                \arrow[ll,"\widetilde h"'] 
                \arrow[ul,"\widetilde g"']
            \end{tikzcd}
        \end{tabular}
\caption{Labels can be swapped with the \texttt{quotes} syntax by adding a
prime.}       
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you edited your answer a quite ago. This answer is satisfactory, thanks.

Comment: @Akerbeltz Yes, I first misread the question, sorry.

Comment: Actually no, your answer was good enough, but afterwards I had the need to do the reflections manually. Good that you actually saw that possibility coming.